# Debug symbols corresponding to a part of the code disappear if that part is placed in a subsection inside .text

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, gdb, linker-scripts

I'm developing a very simple bootloader. I need to assure that my startup code is placed at address `0x0`, so I place it in a 'subsection' called `.isr_vector` inside `.text` as explanined below. The problem I have is that the debug symbols corresponding to that part of the code seem to disappear: I cannot put breakpoints in `startup.s`, in `gdb`, by doing

```
b startup.s:<line_number>
```

because `startup.s` seems to not exist for `gdb`.

Below I have attached a minimal-reproducible-example (although it requires `riscv64-unknown` toolchain to build):

### startup.s

```
.align 2

.section .text

.section .isr_vector

.globl _start
.globl puts

_start:
        csrr    t0, mhartid             
        bnez    t0, halt                
        la      sp, stack_top           
        j       main

halt:   wfi
```

### main.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

### linker.ld

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littleriscv")
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
  /* text: test code section */
  . = 0x20400000;
  .text :
  {
    _text = .;
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata)
    _etext = .;
  }

  /* gnu_build_id: readonly build identifier */
  .gnu_build_id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  /* rodata: readonly data segment */

  /* data: Initialized data segment */
  . = 0x80000000;
  .data :
  {
    _data = .;
    *(.data)
    _edata = .;
  }
  .sdata : { *(.sdata) }
  .debug : { *(.debug) }
  . += 0x1000;
  stack_top = .;

  /* End of uninitalized data segement */
  _end = .;
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)

project(bootloader-test)

include(cmake/toolchain-riscv.cmake)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

add_custom_target(bootld-test-img ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.bin
    BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.bin
)

target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    PRIVATE
        main.c
        startup.s
)

target_link_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    PRIVATE
        -T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/sifive_e_modif.ld
)
```

### toolchain-riscv.cmake

```
enable_language(ASM)
enable_language(C)

# Set cross compilation information
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR riscv)

# GCC toolchain prefix
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX "riscv64-unknown-elf")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)

# Use gcc for assembly files as well
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)

set(CMAKE_AR ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-objdump)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0")
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0")


set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS "")

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS true)
```

If I build this by doing:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The binary is built correctly, and the startup code is at the right position:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -m riscv -D bootloader-test-make.elf | head 

bootloader-test-make.elf:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

20400000 <_start>:
20400000:       f14022f3                csrr    t0,mhartid
20400004:       00029863                bnez    t0,20400014 <halt>
20400008:       5fc01117                auipc   sp,0x5fc01
```

However, if I try to debug it with `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb`, the `startup.s` doesn't seem to exist. If I run the result elf file in qemu, I cannot see the source code corresponding to `startup.s`, although it does jump to `main` correctly.

If I delete the `.section .isr_vector` line from `startup.s`, and I apply the same build steps as above, I am able to put a breakpoint like `b startup.s:5`, but `startup.s` is no longer placed at the beginning of the binary image, which is fatal:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -m riscv -D bootloader-test.elf | head -n 20

bootloader-test.elf:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

20400000 <main>:
20400000:   ff010113            addi    sp,sp,-16
20400004:   00812623            sw  s0,12(sp)
20400008:   01010413            addi    s0,sp,16
2040000c:   00000793            li  a5,0
20400010:   00078513            mv  a0,a5
20400014:   00c12403            lw  s0,12(sp)
20400018:   01010113            addi    sp,sp,16
2040001c:   00008067            ret

20400020 <_start>:
20400020:   f14022f3            csrr    t0,mhartid
20400024:   00029863            bnez    t0,20400034 <halt>
20400028:   5fc01117            auipc   sp,0x5fc01
```

How can I do this correctly, so `_start` is placed at the beginning of the elf file (address 0x0) and `startup.s` is visible for `gdb`?

I have tried to put `startup.s` in a completely separated section name `.isr_vector`. The section is indeed placed at address 0, but I lose its debug symbols again.

## EDIT

These are the build commands extracted from `make`:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc   -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/bootloader-test.elf.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/bootloader-test.elf.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/bootloader-test.elf.dir/main.c.o -c /home/danielgo/test/linker/main.c
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc   -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0 -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0 -o CMakeFiles/bootloader-test.elf.dir/startup.s.o -c /home/danielgo/test/linker/startup.s
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc  -march=rv32g -mabi=ilp32 -static -mcmodel=medany -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -g -O0 -T/home/danielgo/test/linker/sifive_e_modif.ld "CMakeFiles/bootloader-test.elf.dir/main.c.o" "CMakeFiles/bootloader-test.elf.dir/startup.s.o" -o bootloader-test.elf
```

As you can see, all the commands have the `-O0 -g` flags, therefore there should be debug symbols for all files.

Comment: `.section .isr_vector` in the asm source isn't a "subsection", it's a totally separate section from `.text`, making the `.section .text` in the previous line have no effect.  (`.text` is also the default section at the top of an asm source file).  It's only your linker script that does anything about combining those two sections into one ELF program segment.  Your tools might like it better with a name like `.text.isr_vectors`, as GCC uses sections like `.text.cold` and `.text.init`.

Comment: That is strange, I have dumped the sections in my result `elf` file with `objdump -h` and I see the `.text` section, but I don't see any separated `.isr_vector`. Is there any way to tell the linker to place the startup code at the beginning of the `.text` section?

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried to rename my section from `.section .text [...] .section .isr_vector` to `.section .text.isr_vector` and change my linker script to have a completely new section for `.text.isr_vector` (just on top of `.text`) and now everything works. The code is placed at the right address and I have debug symbols, thanks. I will wait in case you want to publish it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know for sure why that worked, that was a lucky guess based on having looked at compiler output, and a guess that `.text*` might imply "progbits" and exec permission, as well as being something that debuggers look for.  So feel free to post an answer yourself.  I'd prefer not to write one based on so much guesswork; perhaps one of the regulars in ELF/linker tags like EmployedRussian will want to write something about exactly why that worked.